# Jump to NavigationController from RootViewController

Tags: ios, ios7, navigationcontroller

My App starts with a `UINavigationController` for my StartViewController (=`UITableViewController`).
It has a Settings button to push to the `UINavigationController` for SettingsViewController (=`UITableViewController`). In it the user has to fill in some credentials which are necessary to further use the App.
(see image for overview)

I want to check if the credentials are filled in and correct, and if not then directly go to the SettingsViewController.

How do I do this? I tried a lot of ways, but mostly the `UINavigationController` doesn't check the direct jump, so I could't get back with the `UINavigationBarButton`s on the left side.

[image: Overview]

Answer (score 0):

You're pushing onto a new UINavigationController with a new backstack. Remove the second UINavigationController and just go directly to your SettingsViewController.

The reason you need to do this is because a UINavigationController manages a backstack of ViewControllers. You can push and pop at will. But when you push another UINavigationController onto the stack it overtakes the previous, making it impossible to just pop back to the first nav controller directly.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. I tried a couple of calls. e.g.: settVC = [[AMMSettingsViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController popToViewController:settVC animated:YES]; BUT I always got errors. Can you give me a code example, too, please!

Comment: I assume since you checked my answer you figured it out? BTW, your comment has an issue - you can't just pop willy nilly to a controller of the same type as the one you want. The instance you want to pop to must already be on the navigation stack. I hope this explains why your attempt to create a ViewController and pop to a different VC of the same type will not work.

Comment: Thanks powerj1984 for your comment. That is my problem. When I understand you right than I have to add the targetVC to the navigation stack but how?  Please give me a code example. I can't figure out a solution.

Comment: That sounds like a different question than the posted one, to be honest. I think my answer answers your first question, this new question however it does not. I really recommend posting a second question for that, but basically if your SettingsViewController is the previous controller on the nav stack just [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like:  if( …credentials are NOT ok… ){ [self.navigationController pushViewController:SettingsViewController animated:YES]; return; } inside StartViewController's viewDidLoad() method.
I hope this help (if i've understood your problem).